# The name 'ExpectedConditions' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I have to perform an action after an element is visible in the UI for this I'm using the below code but ExpectedConditions class is throwing an error saying The name 'ExpectedConditions' does not exist in the current context. Please suggest.

```
public void WaitForElementLoad(By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
    }
}
```

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ExpectedConditions' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***The below will solve your problem***

Make sure you've installed both the `Selenium.Webdriver` and `Selenium.Support NuGet packages` for your project. You'll need the `Selenium.Support package` to use `ExpectedCondition`

***OR***

***Resolve this way:***

1: Using `nuget`, search for `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers,`

2: Import that `namespace` into your `class`.

```
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
```

3: Then example of code `code`:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("element ID")));
```

Comment: I installed both the packages and added Selenium.Support package but still facing the same issue for ExpectedCondition. The second process works best but I want to know why the first process is not working.

Comment: @AmanKhan `ExpectedConditions` was marked as obsolete a long time ago (and looking at the GitHub repo, may have been removed for some time too). 

The DotNetSeleniumExtras provides those capabilities now, but it is also lacking a maintainer at the moment.

Comment: @AmanKhan I agree with James Croft.

Comment: Then what is the better way to satisfy my condition? Any suggestions, please.

Comment: @AmanKhan Use point 1. This is the correct way and makes the obsolete marker disappear. Please read the answer properly. It is correct.

Comment: @JamesCroft I have installed the DotNetSeleniumExtras and SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers packages but both are not compatible with .Net 6.0 that my project is based on.  Is there a package that I can use 'ExpectedConditions' with that is compatible with .Net 6.0?

Comment: @Aidan I've been building a UI testing layer that sits on top of Selenium and Appium for .NET developers to make folks life easier called [Legerity](https://github.com/MADE-Apps/legerity).

In that, some of these `ExpectedConditions` have been migrated to a `Legerity.Core` package under our [`WaitUntilConditions` class](https://github.com/MADE-Apps/legerity/blob/main/src/Legerity.Core/Helpers/WaitUntilConditions.cs)

Comment: @Aidan it's worth noting, you don't have to use all the other features of Legerity to be able to use these helper methods in your existing Selenium UI tests.

And it supports .NET 6 too!

Answer (score 1):

Try using **wait.Until** instead of ExpectedConditions

Example:

```
wait.Until(d => d.Title.Contains("xyz"));
```